# how to extract numbers in the same location from many log files

Tags: linux

I got an file **test1.log**

```
04/15/2016 02:22:46 PM - kneaddata.knead_data - INFO: Running kneaddata v0.5.1

04/15/2016 02:22:46 PM - kneaddata.utilities - INFO: Decompressing gzipped file ...
Input Reads: 69766650 Surviving: 55798391 (79.98%) Dropped: 13968259 (20.02%)
TrimmomaticSE: Completed successfully

04/15/2016 02:32:04 PM - kneaddata.utilities - DEBUG: Checking output file from Trimmomatic : /home/liaoming/kneaddata_v0.5.1/WGC066610D/WGC066610D_kneaddata.trimmed.fastq
04/15/2016 05:32:31 PM - kneaddata.utilities - DEBUG: 55798391 reads; of these:
  55798391 (100.00%) were unpaired; of these:
    55775635 (99.96%) aligned 0 times
    17313 (0.03%) aligned exactly 1 time
    5443 (0.01%) aligned >1 times
0.04% overall alignment rate
```

and the other files in the same format but different contents,like **test2.log**,**test3.log** to **test60.log**

I would like to extract two numbers from these files.For example the `test1.log`, the two numbers would be 55798391 55775635.

So the final generated file `counts.txt` would be something like this:

test1 55798391 55775635

test2 51000000 40000000

.....

test60 5000000 30000000

Comment: Are these values always in the same position (Same line of the file, same part of the sentence/record)?

Comment: have you tried `man grep` ?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same position. The only difference between these log files were the numbers. I have tried grep but had no ideal to output the desired numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'FNR==9{f=$1} FNR==10{print FILENAME,f,$1}' test{1..60}.log
```

if not in the same directory, either call within a loop or create the file list and pipe to xargs awk

```
$ for i in {1..60}; do awk ... test$i/test$i.log; done


$ for i in {1..60}; do echo test$i/test$i.log; done | xargs awk ...
```

Comment: Thanks, karakfa, it is so simple. I think it works if all the log files were in the same directory, but what about test1.log in test1 directory, and test2.log in test2 directory. Is there an alternative way to for-loop thes files?

Comment: BTW, the other thing I forgot to mention:  the log files was actually named in these ways sample_D11.log, sample_M22.log. It was not like test1.log. Maybe I can use for-loop to rename these log files and copy to another directory, so that I can use your suggested way. But It seem a little bit annoying.

Comment: if there is no pattern to automate it, I suggest create a file list with paths either manually or by some trial/error iteration script and use the second alternative.

Comment: I have checked your method for two log files renamed manually, but it came up with the following:
test1.log fastqc_start bmtagger
test2.log fastqc_start bmtagger. I think I have to change the numbers in your method, as I have modified it here.

Comment: So, your real data doesn't match the format you posted?  It's checking lines 9 and 10.  Perhaps there is a pattern you need to match instead of line numbers?  Test with the sample file you posted and verify the results.

Comment: It works at last! as you said, I can tried a for-loop for paths, but it outputs sample_D11.log 11 12 sample_M22.log 10 44 ... something like all these results in the screen. How can it output these for-loop results into a file instead of coping and paste? as it is a really long file.

Comment: add  `> outputfile` at the end.

Comment: will the later output sample overwrite the previous output sample? if I use the specific name output.txt at the end of the for-loop?

Comment: if doing the output within the loop, it will overwrite, then change `>` to `>>` (append).  If you're calling awk outside of the loop (xargs alternative) it's OK.